# Trying to Append a range of data into a designated NAMED sheet in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title describes, however seems to be running into some type of unknown error. Am I just losing my mind here? Or does this have to do with the getValues being a 2D array.

```
function AppendCopy() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Calculation');
var ref = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("B2").getValue();
var sh2=ss.getSheetByName(ref);
var A=sh1.getRange('A2:C').getValues();
sh2.appendRow([new Date(),A]);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the exact output of the console when you run into the error? Also maybe include a few lines about what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is a two dimensional array so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Also when you use  ranges like `A2:C` in script you get nulls between lastrow and maxrows which normally have to be be removed with filter method.

Try is this way:

```
function AppendCopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Calculation');
  var ref = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("B2").getValue();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName(ref);
  var A = sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues().flat().join(', ');
  sh2.appendRow([new Date(), A]);
}
```

I turned A into a string because it's not clear what you are trying to do.  appendRow()  is supposed to just append one row.

After additional consideration perhaps this is what you were looking to do:

```
function AppendCopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ref = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("B2").getValue();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName(ref);
  var A = sh1.getRange(2, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues().map(r => { r.unshift(new Date()); return r; });
  if (sh2.getLastRow() > 1) {
    sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
  } else {
    sh2.getRange(1, 1, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
  }
}
```

This latter solution will append a range of data to the bottom of sh2 with the date inserted into the first column of each row.